# How to modify my ggplot2 codes so that the bars are next to each other rather being stacked?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, geom-bar

I have the following `ggplot2` codes running in `R`. I need to tweak the codes so that the bars of each `FY` value are next to each other rather than being stacked.

My codes stand as follows:

```
 p1 <- ggplot(dff3, aes(x=Gender, fill=FY)) + ggtitle("Gender") + 
       xlab("Gender") +
       geom_bar(aes(y = 100*(..count..)/sum(..count..)), width = 0.5) + 
       ylab("Percentage") + 
       coord_flip() + 
       theme_minimal() +
theme(axis.text=element_text(size=12),axis.title=element_text(size=14,face="bold"))

 p1
```

The plot looks like this:
[image]rently like this:

Comment: Have you tried `position=position_dodge()` within `geom_bar`? Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22793964/adjusting-geom-bar-position-dodge-in-ggplot

Comment: Thanks. Missed that one. Works like a charm.

Comment: Please post as an answer and I'll vote accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `position_dodge()` within `geom_bar()`. Here is an example using `mtcars` dataset:

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=factor(am), fill=factor(vs))) + 
  ggtitle("Gender") + 
  xlab("Gender") +
  geom_bar(aes(y = 100*(..count..)/sum(..count..)), width = 0.5, position = position_dodge()) + 
  ylab("Percentage") + 
  coord_flip() + 
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=12),axis.title=element_text(size=14,face="bold"))
```

[image]