# Why does the stacked bar chart not match values in table?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, tidyverse, stacked-chart

I have a dataset containing cities and prices for specific items in those cities for going out (e.g. taxi, drinks, dinner etc.) - dataset can be found here: https://data.world/makeovermonday/2018w48

I calculated the total sum to pay for a party night and a date night:

```
    CostNightPrepared <- CostNight  %>%
  group_by(City, Category) %>%
  mutate(TotalCost = sum(Cost, na.rm = TRUE))%>%
  arrange(desc(Category), TotalCost)
```

To plot it out:

```
Visual <- ggplot(CostNightPrepared, aes(TotalCost, fct_rev(fct_reorder(City, TotalCost)), fill=Category)) + 
geom_col(position = "stack") +
geom_text(aes(label = round(TotalCost, 1)), position = position_dodge(1))
```

it gives me the following output:

[image]

If you notice, for example, the last city, Zurich, has the value for 179 for "Party Night", however, **the column reachers to around 800 on x axis**! The same goes for all other columns - **they do not match their values for both the "Date night" and "Party Night"**. What is the issue here?

If I do the same code, but using position = dodge for geom_col(), then it works:

```
Visual <- ggplot(CostNightPrepared, aes(TotalCost, fct_rev(fct_reorder(City, TotalCost)), fill=Category)) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(TotalCost, 1)), position = position_dodge(1))
```

Here's the output:

[image]

As you can see, the values match their correspond column sizes (lenghts) on the x axis.

**so why, when using position = "dodge", my columns don't match the actual values in the dataset and have arbitrary values *on the x axis*?**

Comment: If `geom_col` has position stack, then so must have `geom_text`. The positions must match.

Comment: I see my question can sound misleading. The issue is not about the black numbers being at the ends of columns! (this was made only to show exact value of a column). The issue is that the columns do not match the numbers on the X axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `summarize` instead of `mutate`. By using `mutate`, you got the City/Category total for every row, and then fed each of those rows into ggplot2.
You really want one row for each City/Category combination, which is what summarize produces.

Reproducible example:

```
mtcars %>%
head() %>%
  group_by(carb, gear) %>%
  mutate(total_wt = sum(wt)) %>%
  ungroup() -> mtcars_summary
    
#mtcars_summary
## A tibble: 6 x 12
#    mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb total_wt
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
#1  21       6   160   110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4     5.50
#2  21       6   160   110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4     5.50
#3  22.8     4   108    93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1     2.32
#4  21.4     6   258   110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1     6.68
#5  18.7     8   360   175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2     3.44
#6  18.1     6   225   105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1     6.68
```

Note above that `mutate` gives **each row** its group's total weight. ggplot2::geom_col will then stack all the rows it receives, leading to longer bars than you wanted. (Another hint is that the text looks "overplotted" -- this is because every character is being printed once for each row in the group -- ie you might have ten copies of the same text on top of each other, leading to poor anti-aliasing appearance.)

```
ggplot(mtcars_summary, aes(total_wt, 
                           carb %>% as_factor %>% fct_reorder(total_wt), 
                           fill = as.character(gear))) +
  geom_col(position = "stack") +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(total_wt, 1)), position = position_dodge(1))
```

[image]

If we replace `mutate` with `summarize`, we get more what you expected, where the input going into the bars is not repeated for each element in your original data:

```
#mtcars_summary
## A tibble: 4 x 3
#   carb  gear total_wt
#  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
#1     1     3     6.68
#2     1     4     2.32
#3     2     3     3.44
#4     4     4     5.50
```

[image]

Comment: But it's still not correct? In your reproduced example, you still have e.g. 6.7 as a value, but the the column passes the 7.5 mark on the X axis. I used 'summarize()' function instead of 'mutate()', and it did give me a closer result on the X axis, but it is still incorrect - the value of the column doesn't match X axis's value

Comment: 6.7 is the sum for the gear 3 part, 2.3 is the sum for the gear 4 part, 6.7 + 2.3 = 9. In a stacked bar chart the total will be the sum of the components? Are you looking to show a cumulative sum with the text? Are you expecting the bars to all start from the baseline like with the dodged version?

Comment: Actually yes, that was my expectation that they'd start from the baseline like the dodged version and match the values on the X axis

Comment: To clarify, do you want to fix the text, so they show a cumulative total relating to the cumulative x position, or do you want the bars not to stack, so that each bar is only as long as it's own value? (You have already accomplished the 2nd version with the dodging -- perhaps you want the bars to overlap?)

Comment: I would like the bars to overlap then (the final result would be just like with the dodging, but stacked on top). However, this might introduce the issue that that's not the way stacked charts are supposed to be read and one should use dodge?

Comment: Perhaps you want this then: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22794180/6851825

Comment: However, in their example you showed, the overlapping barchart's shorter column overlaps the longer column. In my case it's reverse, which gives the look that shorter columns are "behind" the longer columns and therefore look smaller in width. How can I reverse this?

Comment: Try `ggplot(CostNightPrepared %>% arrange(Category), ...` or `ggplot(CostNightPrepared %>% arrange(desc(Category)), ...`

Comment: haha, just solved it myself like this. Thank you again, you are extremely helpful!